# Return Column number of last Column of a Range With Gaps

Tags: excel, vba

What I'm intending to make, is a macro that will build a scatter plot based off of two columns of data that the user selects.  I need to somehow get what the second column selected was so I can use the correct title.

I've tried the following so far:

```
myrng.Columns(myrng.Columns.Count).Column
```

this returns just 1, since there are gaps in the range.

Is there another method that would work with a range that has gaps in it, or is there perhaps a different way of graphing the data and then finding what the second selected column is?

Comment: In the Visual Basic editor, record a macro of what you are doing manually, when finished hit stop recording, the go to macros and edit the macro you just recorded. There you can see the relevant code to do what you just did manually and then you can enhance as you see fit.

Comment: I'm aware of the record feature in excel. There is no way for me to see how to return a column number using this however.

Comment: `lastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column`?

Comment: In the recorded macro it's certainly telling you the range you selected for the second series, so get the column number from that range.

Comment: That would normally work for me, but there is data outside of the selection range, and that method doesn't limit it to "myrng"

Comment: I'm on a train so can't test. Try Jon Peltier's site, he is the VBA expert on charting.

Comment: dinotom, I need a dynamic code. The same range will never be selected twice. Otherwise yes, that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **r** is some defined range then its limits are:

```
nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
MsgBox ("last row " & nLastRow)

nLastColumn = r.Columns.Count + r.Column - 1
MsgBox ("last column " & nLastColumn)

nFirstRow = r.Row
MsgBox ("first row " & nFirstRow)

nFirstColumn = r.Column
MsgBox ("first column " & nFirstColumn)

numrow = r.Rows.Count
MsgBox ("number of rows " & numrow)

numcol = r.Columns.Count
MsgBox ("number of columns " & numcol)
```

**EDIT#1:**

This will work on any range, compact or disjoint.  It will even work if the range is totally empty.  **However, the sub will be very slow if the range has many cells.**:

```
Sub SlowAgony()
    Dim myrange As Range, r As Range, nLastColumn As Long
    Set myrange = Union(Range("C1:C100"), Range("G1:G100"))

    nLastColumn = 0
    For Each r In myrange
        If r.Column > nLastColumn Then nLastColumn = r.Column
    Next r

    MsgBox nLastColumn
End Sub
```

**EDIT#2:**

This way is quicker:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Dim r As Range, addy As String, ary
    Dim nLastColumn As Long, rr As Range
    Set r = Selection
    addy = r.Address(0, 0)

    If InStr(1, addy, ",") = 0 Then
        nLastColumn = r.Columns.Count + r.Column - 1
    Else
        ary = Split(addy, ",")
        nLastColumn = 0
        For Each a In ary
            Set rr = Range(a)
            If rr.Columns.Count + rr.Column - 1 > nLastColumn Then
                nLastColumn = rr.Columns.Count + rr.Column - 1
            End If
        Next a
    End If

    MsgBox nLastColumn
End Sub
```

The last routine examines the compact components of a disjoint range.

Comment: This works for a range without gaps, but doesn't work for my range since it has gaps in it. Ie, I am selecting columns 3 and 7, and it does not return column 7.

Comment: @Corus  See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: Impressive! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Corus  Your question was very instructive.